# How to redefine the \ce-command in oder to force a specific font?

Tags: fontspec, mhchem

## Prologue

I want to write a document that I can output in both blackletter and latin typefaces just by commenting out a few commands and removing the comment signs from others.
Because German blackletter typesetting rules require the use of latin typefaces for certain stuff (foreign language expressions, formulae etc) I have defined an `\antiquafont` with the help of `fontspec` (loaded by `mathspec`) and also `\antiqua{}` as shown in the MWE.

Everything I'm doing, I'm doing with XeLaTeX.

## The problem

The `mhchem` package takes the surrounding font for its `\ce{}` command. The documentation only mentiones the possibility to enter `sf` and a few other similar in my case hardly helpful options. Since chemical formulae should be typeset in latin even in blackletter documents, and for the ease of writing and editing, I wanted to define a new command (or redefine the `\ce{]` command) so that all `\ce` is generally included in an `\antiqua{}` surrounding.

## The non-working solutions and MWE

My attempts so far failed miserably. Instead of generating an output in latin typeface, I get an ouput in blackletter, consisting of a leading 0 followed by the formula as entered. The only one that worked consistently was enclosing the `\ce{}` in an `\antiqua{}` or `{\antiquafont }` environment but that's exactly the kind of solution I want to avoid.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage{mathspec}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\setmathsfont(Digits,Latin,Greek){LiberationSerif}
\setmathrm{LiberationSerif}
\setmathsf{LiberationSans}
\newfontfamily\antiquafont[Mapping=tex-text]{LiberationSerif}
\newcommand\antiqua[1]{{\antiquafont #1}}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text,Mapping=slong-German]{UnifrakturMaguntia}
\setsansfont[Mapping=tex-text,Mapping=slong-German]{UnifrakturCook}

% Test commands incoming:
\newcommand{\Ace[1]}{{\antiquafont \ce{#1}}}
\newcommand{\Bce[1]}{{\antiquafont\relax \ce{#1}}}
\newcommand{\Cce[1]}{\antiqua{\ce{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\chapter{test chapter}
This is all about the nasty \ce{H2O} which just won't turn into \Ace{H2O}
although {\antiquafont \ce{H2O}} works as fine as \antiqua{\ce{H2O}} does.
The isotope-enriched \Bce{D2O} and \Cce{T2O} don't work as I want them to,
either

\end{document}
```

In the order of appearance, the first gives properly formatted H<sub>2</sub>O in blackletter, the second, fifth and sixth give 0H2O as seen here, and the two in the middle give properly formatted H<sub>2</sub>O in latin typefaces.

## The questions

1. Why is this so?
2. What is the solution/workaround?

Comment: I think `\newcommand{\Ace[1]}` should be `\newcommand{\Ace}[1]` (and the same for the other ones)

Comment: @summer that looks like an answer to me:-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the others mentioned, your approach would work if you wrote

```
\newcommand{\Ace}[1]{{\antiquafont \ce{#1}}}
```

However, you could just skip all that redefining and write

```
\usepackage[version=3,textfontname=antiquafont]{mhchem}
```

in your preamble:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[version=3,textfontname=antiquafont]{mhchem}
\usepackage{mathspec}
\newfontfamily\antiquafont[Mapping=tex-text]{LiberationSerif}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text,Mapping=slong-German]{UnifrakturMaguntia}
\begin{document}
This is all about the \ce{H2O}, which should not be in Fraktur.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Oh, that's so much of a nicer option. Was it just me that I didn't find it in the documentation or is it too well hidden? Thanks a million anyways. =)

Comment: It is in the manual. There, the example of `textfontname=sffamily` is explained. It seems, you thought, that's an option that is hard-coded. However, my intention was that the user can place any font-switching command there.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is simply that

```
\newcommand{\Ace[1]}
```

should be

```
\newcommand{\Ace}[1]
```

(and the same for the other 2 new commands). Note that if you write `\newcommand{\Ace[1]}` you are defining a command `\Ace` which is expecting an argument in brackets (and no argument in curly braces). Thus, in this case you could still achieve the desired result by writing `\Ace[H2O]` in the main document.

Comment: Oh wow, that was absurdly stupid of me. Thanks ^^'